# How to check string contains uppercase letter in golang?

Tags: go

I'm looking a way to check string contains an uppercase. The following code:

```
word := "Hello"
for _,v := range word{
    if .... {
       fmt.Print("contain uppercase letter")           
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at writing the algorithm here to speak of. Try breaking the problem down into steps. Do you know how to loop over characters in a string? Once you've done that, do you know how to check if a character is uppercase? After you have those parts, plop it into a function and return true if any characters are upper while running your loop, otherwise return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check each rune:

```
hasUpper:=false
for _,r:=range word {
   if unicode.IsUpper(r) {
      hasUpper=true
      break
   }
}
```